# Query KDB with java

Tags: kdb

I have a table of String columns called Trade in Kdb.

I have a snippet below to print the table content:

```
c.Flip flip=(c.Flip)c.k("0!select from Trade");

for(int row=0;row<n(flip.y[0]);row++){

for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++)

System.out.print((col>0?",":"")+c.at(flip.y[col],row));

System.out.println();

}
```

All I see as output are unreadable. Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Output:

```
[C@67205a84,[C@7d0587f1,[C@5d76b067,[C@2a17b7b6,[C@4f063c0a,[C@1e6d1014,[C@76707e36,[C@614ddd49,[C@1f554b06,[C@694e1548,func,[C@1c3a4799,[C@131276c2,[C@26aa12dd,[C@3fd7a715,[C@711f39f9,[C@71bbf57e,[C@7f13d6e,[C@51cdd8a,[C@d44fc21,func,[C@23faf8f2,[C@2d6eabae,[C@4e7dc304,[C@64729b1e,[C@10bbd20a,[C@48503868,[C@6895a785,[C@184f6be2,[C@56aac163,[C@1f7030a6,[C@5a1c0542,[C@396f6598,[C@394e1a0f,func,[C@27a5f880,[C@1d29cf23,[C@5f282abb,[C@167fdd33

[C@1e965684,[C@4d95d2a2,[C@53f65459,[C@3b088d51,[C@1786dec2,[C@74650e52,[C@15d0c81b,[C@6acdbdf5,[C@4b1c1ea0,[C@17579e0f,func,[C@4d41cee,[C@3712b94,[C@2833cc44,[C@33f88ab,[C@27a8c74e,[C@2d8f65a4,[C@1b68ddbd,[C@646d64ab,[C@59e5ddf,func,[C@536aaa8d,[C@e320068,[C@1f57539,[C@76f2b07d,[C@704a52ec,[C@6ee52dcd,[C@4493d195,[C@2781e022,[C@57e1b0c,[C@4232c52b,[C@1877ab81,[C@305fd85d,[C@458c1321,func,[C@11438d26,[C@34cd072c,[C@7a1ebcd8,[C@5faeada1

[C@528931cf,[C@ea1a8d5,[C@1563da5,[C@2bbf4b8b,[C@30a3107a,[C@33c7e1bb,[C@34c4973,[C@52feb982,[C@7a765367,[C@76b0bfab,func,[C@17d677df,[C@3043fe0e,[C@78e67e0a,[C@bd8db5a,[C@2f943d71,[C@80503,[C@4b553d26,[C@69a3d1d,[C@86be70a,func,[C@480bdb19,[C@2a556333,[C@7d70d1b1,[C@2a742aa2,[C@3cb1ffe6,[C@3dfc5fb8,[C@467aecef,[C@4d50efb8,[C@7e2d773b,[C@2173f6d9,[C@307f6b8c,[C@7a187f14,[C@6f195bc3,func,[C@51e2adc7,[C@1a8a8f7c,[C@2353b3e6,[C@631330c

[C@42f93a98,[C@c46bcd4,[C@3234e239,[C@3d921e20,[C@36b4cef0,[C@fad74ee,[C@1a1d6a08,[C@37d31475,[C@27808f31,[C@436e852b,func,[C@32d2fa64,[C@1d8d30f7,[C@3e57cd70,[C@9a7504c,[C@2c039ac6,[C@587d1d39,[C@58c1670b,[C@6b57696f,[C@5bb21b69,func,[C@6b9651f3,[C@38bc8ab5,[C@687080dc,[C@23d2a7e8,[C@7a9273a8,[C@26a7b76d,[C@4abdb505,[C@7ce6a65d,[C@1500955a,[C@e874448,[C@29b5cd00,[C@60285225,[C@7113b13f,func,[C@45820e51,[C@42d8062c,[C@6043cd28,[C@cb51256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default toString() implementation of java.lang.Object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

The class name is [C which means it's a char array, which means that the query is returning [(10) char vectors](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/#type-mapping). Easiest way (while not pretty) will be to replace

```
for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++)
System.out.print((col>0?",":"")+c.at(flip.y[col],row));
System.out.println();
```

with

```
for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++) {
    Object rowValue = c.at(flip.y[col],row);
    System.out.print((col>0?",":"") + (rowValue instanceof char[] ? (char[]) rowValue : rowValue));
}
System.out.println();
```

Alternatively you can use the [Arrays.deepToString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) method, but this will include square brackets at the ends of the String.

```
List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
for(int col=0;col<flip.x.length;col++) {
    rowData.add(c.at(flip.y[col],row));
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rowData.toArray()));
```

Comment: Follow up question, how do I check for null in the rowValue. Apparently they just return "func" if null. Is there any other effective way of checking for null aside from comparing it with "func"?

Comment: You can use the following static method to [test if an Object is a null representation of its type](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/#testing-for-null).      

    `qn(rowValue);`      


    Note that the `at()` method actually calls the `qn()` method and returns a Java `null` if the value in kdb is null. So it should have appeared as "null" instead of "func".      
    Having a "func" returned implies that it was a kdb symbol `\`func`. Alternatively it could be a lambda (in-line function) being returned by name.